# how to remove extra { brace in json string in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

can any one suggest me how to remove "{'{\n"before sending request. my api not accepting my parameter be cod of the value are Posting like {'{\n key:values}:""}

here my sample code :

```
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration .defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)

    self.profieImage = UIImage(named: "calendar.png")

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profieImage, 1)

    let params = ["fname":"Martin","lname":"Raj","gender":"Male","dob":"1997-9-14","email":"xx@gmail.com","mobileNumber":"00000","pancard":"vvvv","profileImg":imageData!] as Dictionary!

    let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

    let theJSONText = NSString(data: jsonData,encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    print("JSON string = \(theJSONText!)")


    let urlString = NSString(format:"http://my.api.call");
    print("url string is \(urlString)")
    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: NSString(format: "%@", urlString)as String)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.timeoutInterval = 30
    request.addValue("mobile", forHTTPHeaderField: "true")
    request.addValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "")
    request.HTTPBody = theJSONText!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)



    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        {
            (let data: NSData?, let response: NSURLResponse?, let error: NSError?) -> Void in
            // 1: Check HTTP Response for successful GET request
            guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, receivedData = data
                else {
                    print("error: not a valid http response")
                    return
            }

            switch (httpResponse.statusCode){
            case 200:
                let response = NSString (data: receivedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                print("response==\(response)")

                default:
                break
            }    
    }
```

my BackEnd log prints this statement :

```
 { '{\n  "dob" : "1997",\n  "validatedId" : "sdfdfdf",\n  "pancard" : "rrrrr",\n  "email" : "xx@gmail.com",\n  "sameGender" : "1",\n  "profileImg" : "mobileNumber" : "1230123012",\n  "fname" : "Martin"\n}': '' }
```

but i must send values like this

```
{
"dob" : "1997",
"validatedId" : "dfdsfdsf",
"pancard" : "vvvvv",
"email" : "xx@gmail.com",
"sameGender" : "1"
 }
```

Comment: you must be tel you backend team for correct json response instead of removed from your side. This is the backend webservices developer fault. also you can test the json by using this : http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: thanks for ur reply but can u tell that i entered correct way

Comment: and moreover bro my backend is Amazon so they won't change the condition

Answer (score 1):

in this place

```
 let params = ["fname":"Martin","lname":"Raj","gender":"Male","dob":"1997-9-14","email":"xx@gmail.com","mobileNumber":"00000","pancard":"vvvv","profileImg":imageData!] as Dictionary!
```

no need of this

```
 let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

let theJSONText = NSString(data: jsonData,encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
print("JSON string = \(theJSONText!)")
```

> reason already you creted the dictioanry and again you convert to new JSOn string so that the reason you get combined dictionary, use either single dictionary is enough or use String and convert your string to JSon string

use directly like

```
 let params = ["fname":"Martin","lname":"Raj","gender":"Male","dob":"1997-9-14","email":"xx@gmail.com","mobileNumber":"00000","pancard":"vvvv","profileImg":imageData!] as Dictionary!
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &err)
```

Comment: the reason you crate the another JSOn String instead of params, '

Comment: Thanks bro its worked fine, but another doubt how to convert image as file type